# Check and uncheck the checkbox by row

Tags: php, html, jquery, checkbox

Good Day all...I'm having a multiple row which is fetched from my DB by foreach loop.

And I have 2 checkboxes in each row, What I'm trying is... If I check the 1st checkbox mean automatically the 2nd checkbox need to check.

For that I'm using ID to select that 2nd checkbox, Now because of that id is same for every row, if I select
1st row ,1st checkbox mean it's selecting all the second check box. But what I need is to get that particular selected row's 2nd checkbox need to be checked.
Anyone Help. Sorry for not sharing any live demo like jsfiddle. I hope u guys understand my problem.

```html
<thead>
<th><input type="checkbox" id="select_all"></th>
</thead>

<?php foreach ($category_details as $key => $category_detail): ?>
<tr>
<td>

  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="select_img" name="ids[]" value="<?php echo $category_detail['id'];?>"/>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox checkimg" name="imgs[]" value="<?php echo  $category_detail['category_image'];?>"/>

</td>

<td>...</td> <!-- etc -->
</tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#select_all').on('click',function(){
        if(this.checked){
            $('.checkbox').each(function(){
                this.checked = true;
            });
        }else{
             $('.checkbox').each(function(){
                this.checked = false;
            });
        }
    });

    $('#select_img').on('click',function(){
        if(this.checked){
            $('.checkimg').each(function(){
                this.checked = true;
            });
        }else{
             $('.checkimg').each(function(){
                this.checked = false;
            });
        }
    });

    $('.checkbox').on('click',function(){
        if($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length){
            $('#select_all').prop('checked',true);
        }else{
            $('#select_all').prop('checked',false);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: the id is bad idea, id should be unique in the document and selector by id always will return first matched id

Comment: i will help you if you create one snippet with your jquery and html code at least with a few rows of your input elements

Comment: oh, can u pls share your opinion code which will fulfill my problem in jsfiddle

Comment: Okay i'll create

Comment: here jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/waxq5mpf/1/

Comment: check it out, there is added select all logic when some of checkboxes are not selected... http://jsfiddle.net/user1701/62Lv9r4q/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use siblings jquery function. For example:

```
$('.whole_row').on('click',function(){

    if(this.checked){
    
        $(this).siblings().each(function(index, checkbox){
            checkbox.checked = true;
        });
    }else{
         $(this).siblings().each(function(index, checkbox){
            checkbox.checked = false;
        });
    }
});
```

this way it will iterate the siblings tags and won't go outer the table rows. Just use classes not ids
**Edit:**

just a style note

```
$('.whole_row').on('click',function(){
    let check = this.checked;
    $(this).siblings().each(function(index, checkbox){
        checkbox.checked = check;
    });
});
```

html like this:

```
<tr>
    <input type="checkbox" class="whole_row">one
    <input type="checkbox">two
    <input type="checkbox">three
    <input type="checkbox">four
</tr>
```